# Chrome headless Network.setRequestInterception is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use the [Network.setRequestInterception()](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setRequestInterception) method but it returns the following error:

> TypeError: Network.setRequestInterception is not a function

This is a part of my code:

```
// Launch Chrome
const chrome = await launchChrome({
    headless: !!process.env.APIFY_HEADLESS,
    verboseLog: input.verboseLog
});
const client = await CDP({ port: chrome.port });

// Extract domains
const { Network, Page, Performance, Runtime } = client;

const modifyReq = ['https://www.ford.com/cmslibs/etc/designs/common/core/skin/ford.min.css'];
await Network.setRequestInterception({patterns: modifyReq});
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

Doing `console.log(Network)`, as pritesh asked, returns:

```
setRequestInterceptionEnabled: 
{ [Function: handler]
category: 'command',
experimental: true,
parameters: { enabled: [Object], patterns: [Object] },
description: 'Sets the requests to intercept that match a the provided patterns.' }
```

Which means that `Network.setRequestInterception()` was changed to `Network.setRequestInterceptionEnabled`

Comment: what happens when you console.log Network??

Comment: @pritesh I updated my question. Thanks!